# Eclipse Get via HttpClient

Tags: java, get, apache-commons-httpclient

I have a problem with get request.

1. I'm using Eclipse Juno with correct configured Proxy Settings (I can check for updates and install plugins) My OS is Windows 7.
2. I'm downloaded a and installed `HttpClient 4.2.5` (By copying all jar's into project directory and adding all Build Path's by Eclipse)

3.Java class

```
public class ConnectClass {

public static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

private String cookies;
private HttpClient client;

ConnectClass() {
    client = new DefaultHttpClient();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String vogel = "http://www.vogella.com";

    ConnectClass connect = new ConnectClass();
    try {
        connect.doGet(vogel);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void doGet(String url) throws Exception {

    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
    request.addHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

    System.out.println("Response Code:"
            + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response
            .getEntity().getContent()));

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    String line = "";
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }

}

}
```

4 I have an error

```
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the target host: Network is unreachable: connect
июл 03, 2013 1:53:41 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: Retrying connect
```

1. Error stack trace

   ```
   java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
   at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
   at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
   at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
   at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:127)
   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
   at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:643)
   at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:784)
   at ConnectClass.doGet(ConnectClass.java:49)
   at ConnectClass.main(ConnectClass.java:37)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The proxy preferences in Eclipse itself have no bearing on your program.  You need to change your program to use the necessary proxy.

Probably this section in the Apache HttpClient documentation will help:  [HttpClient proxy configuration](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d5e571)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the `HttpClient` over here. The possible reason is the connection breakdown. It sais that it is retrying to connect - check the firewall issues and if you provide more information, I could help you more.